# Tractrix-like curves

Tags: calculus, geometry, analytic-geometry, plane-curves

Is there a common name for curves, obtained from dragging a point along another curve, similar to how tractrix is obtained by dragging a point along a line?

What is a parametric equation of such curve given the parametric equation of a curve along which the master goes?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Generalized tractrices (tractories) exist, see [this](http://www.2dcurves.com/derived/generalized%20tractrix.html) or [this](http://www-cabri.imag.fr/abracadabri/Courbes/Tract/Tract3.html) or [this](http://www.mathcurve.com/courbes2d/tractrice/tractoire.shtml). (the last two are in French, but with slightly more detail than the first one.)

This [old book](http://books.google.com/books?id=93rvAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA127) ought to be of interest as well.

This [book](http://books.google.com/books?id=f9lAHgWV0vIC&pg=PA176) describes Euler's treatment of the problem of the tractory.

As a note, the problem of finding the generating curve, given the tractory, is a much easier problem (hint: use the tangent vector of a curve) than finding the tractory corresponding to a generating curve.

---

For those who have difficulty reading French, the third link I mentioned gives the prescription for generating the corresponding tractory from a generating curve with parametric equations $(f(t)\quad g(t))$.

The parametric equations for the tractory of $(f(t)\quad g(t))$ (in vector form) is

$$\begin{pmatrix}f(t)\\g(t)\end{pmatrix}-\frac{a}{\sqrt{f^{\prime}(t)^2+g^{\prime}(t)^2}}\begin{pmatrix}\cos\;\alpha(t)&\sin\;\alpha(t)\\-\sin\;\alpha(t)&\cos\;\alpha(t)\end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}f^{\prime}(t)\\g^{\prime}(t)\end{pmatrix}$$

or explicitly

$$\begin{align*}x&=f(t)-\frac{a}{\sqrt{f^{\prime}(t)^2+g^{\prime}(t)^2}}(f^{\prime}(t)\cos\;\alpha(t)+g^{\prime}(t)\sin\;\alpha(t))\\y&=g(t)-\frac{a}{\sqrt{f^{\prime}(t)^2+g^{\prime}(t)^2}}(g^{\prime}(t)\cos\;\alpha(t)-f^{\prime}(t)\sin\;\alpha(t))\end{align*}$$

where the function $\alpha(t)$ satisfies the differential equation

$$\frac{\mathrm d\alpha}{\mathrm dt}=\frac{f^{\prime}(t)g^{\prime\prime}(t)-g^{\prime}(t)f^{\prime\prime}(t)}{f^{\prime}(t)^2+g^{\prime}(t)^2}-\frac{\sin\alpha}{a}\sqrt{f^{\prime}(t)^2+g^{\prime}(t)^2}$$

and $a$ is the length of the segment running through the generating curve.

As an example, here is an animation showing the curve $(3\cos\;t-2\cos^3 t+\cos 2t\quad 2\sin^3 t+\sin 2t)$ and its tractory with segment length 1:

[image: nephroid tractory]

(This is a less fancy version of the last bicycle animation in the third French link.)

Comment: Probably there is a typo in the formula because it is not equation as supposed to be

Comment: Which one do you think has the typo, @Anixx?

Comment: "The parametric equations for the tractory is" is not equation...

Comment: @Anixx: Multiply out the (rotation) matrix and the vector, and add up the vectors. The components yield the parametric equations. I only chose matrix-vector representations here because it's more intuitive (at least, for me).

Comment: It should be equal to zero?

Comment: @Anixx: $x$ is the first component of the vector; $y$ is the second component.

Comment: I do not see x and y, only f, g and alpha and there is no equation....

Comment: You said there is a parametric equation, but there is no equation sign in it.

Comment: @Anixx: \*sigh\* it's vector notation. The components of the vector are taken to correspond to $x$ and $y$ coordinates...

Comment: Ok, alpha is the vector? But where is the equation? I see no equality sign...

Comment: @Anixx: $\alpha$ is a scalar function. I guess you aren't accustomed to vector notation... I'll edit this answer to give the explicit parametric equations.

Comment: Thanks but still cannot understand how an equatioc can be without equality...

Comment: Oh now I see the result of the expression should be the $(x,y)^T$ vector. It is just omitted but there should be an equality sign.

Comment: Interesting, is it possible to have an explicit expression for alpha?

Comment: @Anixx: it's kind of implied... it is a two-component vector after all. The DE for $\alpha(t)$ isn't always easy to solve, but for the usual tractrix, it's pretty easy. For the *Mathematica* animation, I used `NDSolve[]` since it's quicker.

Comment: What is tractory of a circle? This simple case should be written somewhere in the French text. May resemble a cardoide.  Can you please pick it out for me? Thanks.

Comment: @Narasimham, [it was linked in that page.](http://www.mathcurve.com/courbes2d/tractrice/tractoiredecercle.shtml)

Comment: Trying to get a curved tractrix of Trumpet [![Bugle horn][7]][7]
[7]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jaIjZ.png

Answer (score 0):

Some of them are called [pursuit curves](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PursuitCurve.html).

Comment: They're similar, but the tractrix is not identical to the pursuit curve for a straight line. For one thing, the pursuit curve has no cusp.

Comment: Pursuit curves have no fixed length between dragging and dragged object. This is not the case for a straight-line tractrix.