# constant tangent curve elements

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, curves

I have to write a paper with a title Curves with a constant tangent elements, but I have no idea what those curves are. I have been searching in the literature we've been given, but the truth is I really have no idea what to look for. Please help? The paper is part of differential equations class, if that is of any help. I have to find 4 different examples and solve them.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

I suggest you have a look at http://hom.wikidot.com/the-tractrix. You will see that these curves obey a quite simple differential equation $$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{y}{\sqrt{a^2-y^2}}$$ which is separable. Using parametrization leads to quite simple equations.

Comment: @Leibovici Your answer is probably right but the website you linked seems to contain malware. Are you sure this is the website you meant?

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Tractrix.html http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10255/tractrix-like-curves could be safer.